# document.body.style.backgroundImage vs document.body.background

Tags: javascript, html

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**document.body.background** refers to the deprecated background attribute of the body tag

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_body_background.asp

**document.body.style.backgroundImage** refers to the CSS background-image property of the body tag. It is equivalent to something like...

```
body { 
  background-image:url('paper.gif');
}
```

Use the latter :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a third important entry to consider in addition to the depracated `document.body.background` and the way to change the CSS background image with `document.body.style.backgroundImage`.... You can use `document.body.style.background` to change all the background properties, including color image and repeat:

```
document.body.style.background = "red";
```

or, to set more than one property

```
document.body.style.background="#0000FF url(example.jpg) repeat-x";
```

The above sets a background color, a background image, and sets a horizontal repeat for that image.

This is similar to the CSS:

```
body {
    background:#0000FF url('example.jpg') repeat-x; }
```

( here's a little more [**info about document.body.style.background**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp) at W3Schools... I'm sure there's more complete info elsewhere though )

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.background`: You are not using CSS.

`document.body.style.backgroundImage`: you are setting using CSS.